# Почему не закрывается Меню при отведении курсора с Menubutton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, события

Сделал открытие меню при наведении курсора на `ttk.Menubutton`, но к сожалению не получается его закрыть когда курсор находиться не на кнопке. Подскажите, как такое реализовать? Какое событие надо генерировать чтобы закрывалось меню вызваное из `Menubutton`?

### Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)

fr = ttk.Frame(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn =ttk.Button(fr, text='grfbvgfev')
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn_menu_st =ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='gtg')
btn_menu_st.grid(row=0, column=3)

fr.pack(fill='x')


#print(btn_menu.configure())

def open_menu2(e):
    e.widget.event_generate('<<Invoke>>')

file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style = tk.Menu(btn_menu_st, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
style.add_command(label='Ugu')

#btn_menu.config(background='black', foreground='white', indicator=0, direction='below', state='active')
btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
btn_menu_st.configure(menu=file)

btn_menu_st.bind('<Enter>', open_menu2)
btn_menu.bind('<Enter>', open_menu2)
btn_menu_st.bind('<Leave>', open_menu2)
btn_menu.bind('<Leave>', open_menu2)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: здесь информация, почитайте http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm посмотрите ссылку

Comment: Да, там информация про меню, но я хотел сделать своё меню. Всё это из-за того что такое меню, которое указано в вашей ссылке - нельзя модифицировать. То есть я не могу поменять задний фон строки меню(которая прикреплена к заголовку окна), а стандартное серое с темной темой смотрится не очень хорошо.